# Somar dias ao Javascript Date() no formato dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: javascript

Olá,
Como faço para mostrar a data gerada no formato brasileiro? Pesquisei aqui e na internet, mas não consegui executar como preciso.

Veja:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#button").click(function() {
        
        var dias = 2;
        var dataAtual = new Date();
        var previsao = dataAtual.setDate(dataAtual.getDate() + dias);    
  
  $("#dPrev").val(dataAtual);
        
        
  
 }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>




<input name="dPrev" type="text" class="form-control" id="dPrev" value=""  placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" required >

    
    <button type="submit" id="button" name="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right"></i> Salvar</button>
```

Ele pega a data atual, acrescenta dias e precisa mostrar no campo como DD/MM/AAAAA

Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Tiago, uma boa opção é usar um plugin como o [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) eu gosto de trabalhar com ele. Recomendo. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Uma das formas de resolver esse problema seria assim:

```
var dias = 2;
var dataAtual = new Date();
var previsao = dataAtual.setDate(dataAtual.getDate() + dias);       

var dataBrasil = previsao.getDate() + "//" + previsao.getMonth() + "//" + previsao.getFullYear();

("#dPrev").val(dataBrasil);
```

Outra forma seria adicionar um método à classe Date:

```
Date.prototype.toDataBrasil = function () {
    return this.getDate() + '//' + this.getMonth() + '//' + this.getFullYear();
};
```

E depois usar ela assim:

```
var dataBrasil = previsao.toDataBrasil();
```

Comment: A data atual tem que somar com a variável `dias`

Comment: Sim, mas eu deixei essa soma na resposta

Comment: Não funciona, veja http://jsfiddle.net/5n73cL2j/2/

Comment: @Tiago é só alguns erros de syntax: http://jsfiddle.net/5n73cL2j/3/

Comment: @KaduAmaral Show de bola. Mas como é feito para mostrar a tada cheia, quando tem 0, não mostra, veja http://jsfiddle.net/5n73cL2j/4/, teria que mostrar **01/06/2015**

Comment: @KaduAmaral consegue me ajudar com a questão acima para finalizar?

Comment: @KaduAmaral, um detalhe que reparei. O Mês esta ficando como data passada. Hoje é mês 06, no código esta mostrando mês 05

Comment: Consegue me ajudar? A data esta ficando errado, veja http://jsfiddle.net/5n73cL2j/6/

Comment: @Tiago Está retornando 5 porque ele começa a contar do 0. Assim Janeiro = 0, e Dezembro = 11. Aqui exemplo funcionando http://jsfiddle.net/odex98qj/

Comment: @Tiago http://jsfiddle.net/5n73cL2j/7/

Comment: Observe que somar assim: `dataAtual.getDate() + dias` não vai funcionar, pois ele não vai ajustar qdo for final de mês. Você precisa transformar para Time, e então somar os dias, para depois pegar a data somada com `getDate()`

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#button").click(function() {
        
        var dias = 2;
        var dataAtual = new Date();            
        var previsao = new Date();

        previsao.setDate(dataAtual.getDate() + dias);    
        n = previsao.getDate()  +"/" + (previsao.getMonth() + 1)+ "/" + previsao.getFullYear();
  $("#dPrev").val(n);
 }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>




<input name="dPrev" type="text" class="form-control" id="dPrev" value=""  placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" required >

    
    <button type="submit" id="button" name="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right"></i> Salvar</button>
```

Comment: Tem que somar a data atual com a variável `dias `

Comment: Mas tem que mostrar como DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: Consegue me ajudar? A data esta ficando errado, veja http://jsfiddle.net/5n73cL2j/6/

Comment: pra vc não quebrar a cabeça [baixa](http://momentjs.com/) e na variavel põe assim:`  $("#dPrev").val( moment().format('MMM D, YYYY') );`

Comment: +1 nossa reduzi para 2 linas somente. Atualiza seu código para eu dar uma qualificação. http://jsfiddle.net/5n73cL2j/8/